# Resize a persistent disk for Linux (MBR partition) on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: linux, hard-drive, google-compute-engine, partition

I want to expand my disk capacity for my Google Cloud machine and have been following the tutorial that's located [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/resize-persistent-disk).

However, I'm fairly certain that the tutorial assumes the user has a GPT partition table but I have MBR. I only need 20GB so this shouldn't be a problem.

Anyway, I followed the tutorial up to step 4a and everything seemed to execute just fine including everything involved with the command `sudo parted /dev/sda`.

But, when I reached step 4b which tells you to run `sudo sgdisk --move-second-header /dev/sda`, I got the following message:

```
Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table

entries is 1119092736 bytes, but this program supports only 128-byte entries.

Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.

Warning: Partition table header claims that the size of partition table

entries is 0 bytes, but this program supports only 128-byte entries.

Adjusting accordingly, but partition table may be garbage.


***************************************************************

Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format

in memory.

***************************************************************



Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by

33 blocks!

You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Non-GPT disk; not saving changes. Use -g to override.
```

I'm lost as to what to do next. Right now, I have the 20GB available yet my sda1 says that it's only 10GB.

In case it helps, here is the output of `sudo df -Th`:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  976M     0  976M   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     199M  716K  198M   1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4      9.8G  8.6G  720M  93% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     992M     0  992M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/loop5     squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1611
/dev/loop2     squashfs   45M   45M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2344
/dev/loop6     squashfs   64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/1623
/dev/loop4     squashfs  115M  115M     0 100% /snap/core/13741
/dev/loop1     squashfs  115M  115M     0 100% /snap/core/13886
/dev/loop0     squashfs   45M   45M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2414
tmpfs          tmpfs     199M  4.0K  199M   1% /run/user/1000
```

And here is the output of `sudo lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  44.7M  1 loop /snap/certbot/2414
loop1    7:1    0   115M  1 loop /snap/core/13886
loop2    7:2    0  44.5M  1 loop /snap/certbot/2344
loop4    7:4    0 114.9M  1 loop /snap/core/13741
loop5    7:5    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1611
loop6    7:6    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1623
sda      8:0    0    20G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0    20G  0 part /
```

Comment: Are you resizing the disk online and are you using a custom image? It is a best practice to resize the persistent disk offline or attached as an additional disk on a separate VM Instance and run the command sudo resize2fs /dev/sda. Be sure to take a snapshot first as backup

Comment: I'm not using a public image if that's what you're asking. All I need to know is what to do next. The linked tutorial says nothing about online/offline and of course I took a snapshot. To reiterate, I've done everything up to and including step 4a.

Comment: Run the command `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda` and skip `sudo sgdisk --move-second-header /dev/sda` since the free remaining space is recognized by the lsblk

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` and skip `sudo sgdisk --move-second-header /dev/sda` since the free remaining space is recognized by the `lsblk`

Comment: What about step 5?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you should run `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1` as you are using the persistent disk as boot disk. step 5 is only run for additional disk attached on your VM